# Can't get rid of Uni launcher on my Android 5.1

Tags: applications, uninstallation, launcher, malware

I have tried to uninstall it (for me it is malicious software because I do not know when and how have I obtained it) through settings and reboot my phone but it keeps coming back and blocks my phone, constantly offering some options with no other possibility as confirming access or installation.

Comment: If what you noted [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/136873/96277) is true, then your device's integrity has been compromised. It is not worth taking risk by continuing using an infected OS. Have the stock ROM flashed on it. You may do it on your own or find a service center and get the job done.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum with threads and replies. If you have more information to add to your question, you can [edit] the question to add it. Posting answers to your own question just means other people might think you've solved the problem already.

Answer (score 0):

Uni Launcher is indeed malware, and will install other software silently where it is able to do so.

If your phone happens to be a HOMTOM HT7 (you didn't specify a model), you'll want to install the [latest update](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=65475308&postcount=151) from the manufacturer (2.0.3). This will remove the malware by replacing the launcher, and also fix some other issues.

**Update:** Supposedly a 2.0.7 update has been released now as well, but [some people have indicated issues](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/homtom-ht7-t3251520/page38) with this particular version.

Comment: I guess you got this information from [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/homtom-ht7-t3251520/page4)? It'd be better to provide references/sources to backup your answer.

Comment: That was one of several sources I've run across - but yes, it would've probably been a good idea to add the reference. I'll do that in a moment.

Answer (score -1):

try this:
***Settings*** -> ***Application Manager*** -> Under the ***All*** tab, search for the launcher and select it. Now click on ***Uninstall for all Users***
If ***Uninstall for all Users*** is not available at first, then first ***Uninstall*** an then try ***Uninstall for all Users***